# How to install multiple dotnet versions using brew?

Tags: c#, macos, homebrew, dotnet-cli

I am trying to install .NET 6 and 7 on my Mac (M1 chip) and after trying several approaches, I am going nowhere.

**Option-1:** Using `brew`

- Installed [.NET 7](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dotnet). Here, I see successful installation under `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100` which is good.
- Installed [.NET 6](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dotnet@6). This is installed under `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet@6/6.0.114`

When I run `dotnet --list-runtimes` then I only see `7.0.0`.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0 [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/libexec/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/libexec/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I get that brew command creates `dotnet@6`.

How can I have this with `.NET 7` so that I don't run into `You must install or update .NET to run this application.` error?

**Option-2:** Using `Install-scripts`.

- I installed [dotnet-install scripts](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/scripts) from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) (chose `.NET Runtime 6.0.20`).
- Then ran following commands

```
chmod +x dotnet-install.sh
sudo ./dotnet-install.sh --runtime dotnet --version 6.0.20 --install-dir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet 
sudo ./dotnet-install.sh --runtime aspnetcore --version 6.0.20 --install-dir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet
```

- When I ran `dotnet --list-runtimes` again, then it just showed `7.0.0`. Here, I was expecting the above command to create a new folder, like `6.0.20` similar to `7.0.100` but it didn't. All files were directly installed under `dotnet` folder.
- Reference, https://danielhilton.medium.com/how-to-install-multiple-asp-net-core-runtimes-in-macos-717e8d0176ea

**Option-3**-Using Installers and [SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.412-macos-arm64-installer) and [Runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-6.0.20-macos-arm64-installer) which installs successfully, but I end up seeing `7.0.0` only.

My end goal is to fix the following error: How to fix this?

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/USERNAME/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-ef/6.0.14/dotnet-ef/6.0.14/tools/net6.0/any/tools/netcoreapp2.0/any/ef.dll
Architecture: arm64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' (arm64)
.NET location: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/libexec/

The following frameworks were found:
  7.0.0 at [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/libexec/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=arm64&rid=osx.13-arm64
```

**Additional Info:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I'm using [homebrew-dotnet-sdk-versions](https://github.com/isen-ng/homebrew-dotnet-sdk-versions)

```bash
brew tap isen-ng/dotnet-sdk-versions
brew install --cask dotnet-sdk6-0-400
dotnet --list-sdks
```

This way **multiple versions can be used in parallel**.

In your .net code you might need to define which version to use in a file called `global.json` in the root folder:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.412"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After spending almost a day and half, I think following approach is easiest one which worked for me:

- Delete .NET installed via Brew by running `brew uninstall dotnet`
- I would recommend delete all .NET by using [.NET uninstall tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows) and do fresh installation.
- Use Microsoft installer for respected .NET version. i.e., This is for [.NET 7](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.306-macos-arm64-installer)

  - If you are using a Mac with M1 chip, then use ARM64. For intel, you can use X64.

Result:

As you can see, `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/` is gone now (due to uninstallation) and all .NET versions are coming from `user/local/....` path, which is the key. Here, all your future installation will be in this path, so you don't have to worry about it later on.

[image]

If you are using `.zshrc` file then you can set `usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:$PATH` for `export PATH=`.

Comment: This does not solve it using brew though. I do not want to install it using MS installer (same as the person who asked the question)

Comment: @maulik13 it was me who asked (and added the answer). I do not want to use `brew` for this, so went with this route.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply xcopy files over to the `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/` installation folder.

For example:

```bash
cp /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet@6 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet
```

These files are all meant to live in the same dotnet folder. No idea why brew and other installs are doing something dumb.

EDIT: Looks like there is no `xcopy` command in Mac OS. The alternative is `cp`, it might also need a `sudo`.

Comment: Well, I tried doing copy/paste manually, but the command shows same results. i.e., I see both .NET versions under `/dotnet` folder but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be useful, but here's a thought I had.

## Finder & text editor

1. Open .zshrc in your Home directory
2. add text into your .zshrc:

   alias dotnet7="/usr/local/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/bin/dotnet"

   alias dotnet6="/usr/local/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet@6/6.0.114/bin/dotnet"

   // For changes in your .zshrc file to take effect, you'll need to restart
   your terminal session.
3. Then, you can use either dotnet6 or dotnet7:

   dotnet6 new blazorserver -o BlazorApp
4. It's always worth considering other possibilities. Perhaps someone else
   has a different approach that might be even more effective.

Comment: This will end up in creating multiple aliases which I want to avoid.

Comment: You right! sorry about that.